# Directional Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given the following equation:

$V(x,y,z)=5x^2-3xy+xyz$

Part 1: 
At point $P(3,4,5)$, find the rate of change in the direction of the vector $\langle1,1,-1\rangle$

Part 2: **Find the direction in which $V$ changes most rapidly at $P(3,4,5)$**

Part 3: **Find the maximum rate of change at $P(3,4,5)$**

---

I think I've managed to do part 1. Here's what I've done so far - but I am clueless as to how to find the max rate of change at $P$ and the direction in which the change occurs most rapidly.

$V_x(x,y,z)=10x+y(z-3)$

$V_y(x,y,z)=x(z-3)$

$V_z(x,y,z)=xy$

Based on the above partial derivatives,

$$\begin{align}
\nabla V(3,4,5) &=\left.\langle10x+y(z-3),\ x(z-3),\ xy\rangle\right|_{(3,4,5)} \\
&=\langle38,6,12\rangle
\end{align}$$

Unit vector of $\langle1,1,-1\rangle$ is $\vec u=\langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\rangle$.

Directional derivative at $(3,4,5)$ in the direction of $\langle1,1,-1\rangle$ is:
$$\begin{align}
D_\vec uV(3,4,5) &= \nabla V(3,4,5) \cdot \vec u \\
&=\frac{32}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: There is a small mistake. The unit vector of $(1,1,-1)$ is $\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\big)$.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! Updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand clearly what's going on, I'm going to restrict myself to two dimensions (i.e. $z=0$).

In this case
$$
\tilde V(x,y) = V(x,y,0) = 5 x^2 -3 xy
$$

The directional derivative in the direction $\vec{\alpha}$ is
$$
\frac{\partial \tilde V}{\partial \vec{\alpha}} = \nabla \tilde V \cdot \frac{\vec{\alpha}}{\|\vec{\alpha}\|}
$$
hence
$$
\frac{\partial \tilde V}{\partial \vec{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{\|\vec{\alpha}\|}\big(\tilde V_x \alpha_1 + \tilde V_y \alpha_2)
$$
where $\vec{\alpha} = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2)^T$.

As a function of $\alpha$, in $(3,4)$
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{\alpha}} \tilde V(3,4) = \frac{18 \alpha_1 - 9 \alpha_2}{\sqrt{\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2}}
$$
we
have
$$
\nabla_{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{\alpha}} \tilde V(3,4)\right) = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{9\alpha_2(\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2)}{(\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2)^{3/2}}\\
-\frac{9\alpha_1(\alpha_1 + 2\alpha_2)}{(\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2)^{3/2}}\\\end{pmatrix}
$$
and if $\alpha_1 = -2 \alpha_2$, $\nabla_{(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{\alpha}} \tilde V(3,4)\right) = 0$, hence, the direction in which $V$ changes *critically* is
$$
\vec{\alpha} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\begin{pmatrix}2 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

$\hskip1.5in$[image: In blue, the contour passing trough the point (3,4)]

The maximum rate of change would be
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec{\alpha}} \tilde V(3,4) = 9\sqrt{5}
$$
in the direction $(2,-1)$.

Note that the contour $\tilde V(x,y) = 9$, which passes through $(3,4)$ can be expressed *locally* using the [Implicit Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) as a function $g(x)$, where
$$
g'(x) = -\frac{\tilde V_x}{\tilde V_y}
$$
as long as $\tilde V_y \neq 0$. In $(3,4)$
$$
g'(3) = 2
$$
**The direction of min/max growth of a function is *normal* to the level curve passing trough it!**

This is very usefull for finding local maxima/minima of a function, an there is a method called  [Gradient Descent Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent_method) that depends upon this property.

A fantastic excercise would be to prove this result in general ;)

Comment: What sort of tool did you use to draw the picture ?

Comment: @guanglei Mathematica